# How to install symfony cmf with an existing Symfony 2 project?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I would like to install Symfony CMF into an existing Symfony2 project.

I am using [this documentation](http://symfony-cmf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-configuring-cmf.html#download-the-bundles).

After running `php composer.phar update`, I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]

  Could not read http://packagist.org/packages-dev-n.json, either you or the remote host is probably offline.

  The "http://packagist.org/packages-dev-n.json" file could not be downloaded

update [--prefer-source] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-scripts] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Content-type: text/html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output give `wget -S http://packagist.org/packages-dev-n.json` ?

Comment: I have been changed composer.json like this `{ "require": {

  "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "dev-master"

    }
}` After this i have `Installing dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master -> satisfiable
 by symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master.
    - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> no ma
tching package found`. Maybe i must set some data in composer.lock file?

Comment: It seems to have problem in `composer.json` from the github source. You might try by manually adding all the [`require`](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf/blob/master/composer.json) section in your own composer.json.

Comment: Can you post your full composer.json?